# Code to update dense QR and Cholesky factorizations

Tags: linear-algebra, libraries, lapack, matrix-factorization

I am looking for some production-ready code to update dense QR and/or Cholesky factorizations (by adding / removing rows and columns or making small-rank updates -- yes, I need all these cases).

I have done my <strike>Google</strike>literature research, but I have found very little:

- Matlab has this [covered](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qrupdate.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), but unfortunately this is for a C++ project, so it is not easy to interface with it. I'd much rather have C/C++ or Fortan, especially the "traditional" LAPACK-style code.
- LAPACK has nothing, as far as I can tell. There was something in LINPACK (LAPACK's precursor), but as far as I can tell it has not been updated in the last 30 years at least.
- There is some [code](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~clucas/updating/) by Craig Lucas for one of these subtasks (adding/deleting columns only for a QR factorization), and some [code](http://anchp.epfl.ch/QRupdate) by Daniel Kressner for adding rows to a QR factorization only. Both of them are only limited to one of the subtasks that I need, and, to quote Kressner's page,

> It is not tested thoroughly and should be understood as research code.

- Surprisingly, there is mature code for the same task for sparse matrices, in Tim Davis' [Suitesparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html). I don't suppose that the code will be efficient on a dense matrix.
- Michael Saunders' [LUSOL](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lusol/) has the corresponding code for a (sparse) LU factorization (unsymmetric case).

So it seems like there is plenty of code for doing *similar* and *related* tasks, but not exactly for this problem, which seems surprising.

Am I overlooking some obvious choice? Is there a library to do it?

Comment: Look at algorithm 686 from the ACM TOMS Library: [FORTRAN subroutines for updating the QR decomposition](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=98291). There is a link to the FORTRAN 77 code on that same page. The paper can also be downloaded from [here](http://calhoun.nps.edu/bitstream/handle/10945/38295/inc_Gragg_Mathematics_1990.pdf).

Comment: Do you not have access to Matlab Coder ([`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html))? The output from that might not be the easiest to integrate, but I think one could write a simple LAPACK-style interface to the resultant C/C++.

Comment: @horchler I don't think our academic license covers that. Anyway, `qrupdate` is not Matlab code, but a built-in binary blob. Does codegen work also with those? Would I need to ship some Matlab libraries with it? And what would be the licensing status of the resulting code + libraries?

Comment: Yes, `codegen` works with [many compiled Matlab functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html). I thought that `qrupdate` would be supported, but sadly it appears that it isn't (I confirmed with a small test). You might find [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/package-code-for-other-development-environments.html) helpful for deployment. As far as licensing goes, see section 5 of `edit([matlabroot filesep 'license_agreement.txt'])` (starts at line 1177 in my version).

Comment: Anyway you can try to implement it by yourself reading paragraph 12.5.1 of this book: Golub, Gene H. and Charles Van Loan, Matrix Computations, Third Edition, Johns Hopkins University Press, Baltimore, 1996 (If you google it you can find a copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package [qrupdate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qrupdate/files/qrupdate/1.1/qrupdate-1.1.1.tar.gz/download) that is the one linked in Octave.

It's in Fortran... but it should be self contained. If you need to link it to a C++ project you can look at the Octave [source code](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.gz), file `floatQR.cc`.